# How to create new application for nokia 6212

Tags: java

I try to run my P2P NFC project in nokia 6212 emulator. but the application is not showing on the emulator screen.
so, my question is it is possible to create an application for nokia6212. if it does then kindly inform me the steps. 
actually, m running my p2p java projects in eclipse. Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer: Yes.

Take a look at this [example](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Simple_NFC_LLCP_peer-to-peer_Chat).

All needed steps, including code examples, getting started, tutorials, etc.. are [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!index.html).

Comment: Hi Asier,
   Actually when i run the simple NFC LLCP peer-to-peer chat ( http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Simple_NFC_LLCP_peer-to-peer_Chat )  the invalid service id SID=35 exception is throwing on the emulator. do you have any idea why this exception is throwing?
btw,your answer is very helpful, thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Take a look at the configuration parameters:      * Connection param
     * @note
     * Connection URI to open a Type 2 connection that uses service identifier
     * (SID) 35. Note that PID mentioned in the SDK javadocs is not valid, use SID
     * instead. 
     * Tested with SID 35 on the C7; Symbian supports SIDs from 32 - 63.
     * Use SIDs between LLCPConnection.MIN_SERVICE_ID and MAX_SERVICE_ID on Series 40.

Comment: So, try changing the SID between those parameters ; )

Comment: hi, 
  can we run 2 nokia 6212 emulator simultaneously on same PC.
  Actually, i want to test the LLCP demo between two emulator by passing string from one of the emulator to other.. it's possible to do this.. any idea?
thanks

Comment: Uff, have no idea about it. I didn't really know anything about this, just found some answers on the internet and thought they could be helpful for you. But i'm not an expert! ; )

Comment: hi, i have change with all the SID from 32-63, but still i cannot solved my problem.. the same error is coming out "invalid SID". so, do you have further solution. btw, i can't undestand this part of your comment " Note that PID mentioned in the SDK javadocs is not valid, use SID * instead.".
thanks